Loop in r with subset makes incomplete selection
I have a data frame (words) containing words with five letters, in which each letter appears in one of five columns. The sixth column represents the log probability of the word based on letter frequency.




v1
v2
v3
v4
v5
ln_freq_




1
s
e
i
n
e
-10.54397


2
s
o
u
s
e
-10.74434


3
c
r
a
s
e
-10.74434



etc.
I want to create a second data frame in which no rows include the letter s or i
This loop only seems to eliminate rows containing the letter i
eliminate<-c('s', 'i')
for (j in 1:length(eliminate))
  {
  words_625<-subset(words, v1!=eliminate[j] & v2!=eliminate[j] & v3!=eliminate[j] & v4!=eliminate[j] & v5!=eliminate[j])
}

I've written more complex loops than this that did what I wanted, and I'm not sire what do do here.

Share your data using dput() and your expected output

use the code:
df %>%
  filter(if_all(everything(), ~!(.x %in% eliminate)))


In base R one way is to do:
subset(df, !rowsum(+(unlist(df) %in% eliminate), c(row(df))))


subset(df, !rowSums(Reduce(`|`,lapply(eliminate, `==`, df))))


subset(df, !rowSums(array(unlist(df) %in% eliminate, dim(df))))


Thanks everyone for these solutions. They will definitely improve the way I do this in the future. So last night, driving, I realized with the original loop wasn't working--In the first round of the loop, it subsets words from words that don't contain 's'.  However in the second round, it goes back to words (which includes words containing 's') and repeats the subset,only removing words that contain 'i'. So it just overwrites words_625 with words missing 'i', but that HAVE 's'. Here's the fix. Start by assigning words to words_625 and sample from that in both rounds of the loop.

code below in answers

words_625<-words
eliminate<-c('s','i')
for (i in 1:length(eliminate))
  {
  words_625<-subset(words_625, v1!=eliminate[i] & v2!=eliminate[i] & v3!=eliminate[i] & v4!=eliminate[i] & v5!=eliminate[i])
}


This code is very inefficient. Suppose you had 1000 columns to check. You will not be able to write everything. ie v1....v1000. Thats why you do it dynamically as the code I provided above. This also is hard coded in that the data passed MUST only contain 5 columns with specified names of v1...v5

No...you're absolutely right. Very inefficient. I'm not recommending that anyone do it this way, so much as indicating why it didn't work for even 5 columns. Your way is much better.
